# Pulling data from Crystal Reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, report

My data is stored in Oracle and the only way I can run a report with it is using Crystal Reports. I have a set of data that looks like this `,,,,,,,,,,1,` or `,1,,,,,,,` or `,1,,,,,1,,,,1,`.  There are more variations.

Each one means a value is true for a record.  There are about 54 'ticks/commas' What I want is all records with the one at the X spot.  So for one report I may want all records in the 10th spot that have a 1. There may be other times where I want the records where the 1 is after spot 36. I agree it will pull other records but the main once I want is the X spot.

How do I get this? I tried a Like command but that does not narrow the data down far enough. I am familiar with SQL but not Crystal.

Any help would be great. TIA

Comment: for me, it would be comfortable if you pick up the data with stored procedure and from that you will call that stored procedure to crystal reports

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal, you might try setting up a Parameter Field to hold a numeric value (1 to 54) then use that in a formula as the Record Selection. You'll be prompted to enter the parameter when you run the report.

Answer (score 0):

In record selection i was initially going suggest the following which would bring back all records with 1 in the 12 spot. But this makes it hard to bring back a range.

```
split({yourfield},",")[12] = 1
```

This will bring back the same

```
instr({@test},"1") = 12
```

Then for your suggestion above you could use the following to bring back any record if it has a one in any spot after 36

```
instr({@test},"1") >= 37
```

As long as there is only one 1 in the field you can use this for other ranges as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't want to disturb both answerts by `Clayton Morris` and `CoSpringsGuy` hence posting my answer.

You need to combine both the solutions to get the desired result.

1. Create a number parameter and provide either 1 to 57 numbers or keep just a filed to enter desired number.
2. Now in record selection use the formula given by `CoSpringsGuy`

`if instr({databasefield.column},"1") = {?Inputnumber} --parameter field
then {databasefield.column}`